# Can VisualStudio autocomplete be like Eclipse's one

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete

I am starting to write in C#. I use VisualStudio, but I don't like the autocomplete. I was mainly writing in Android and I really like the autocomplete of AndroidStudio and Eclipse. It there a way to make the VisualStudio's one the same? I don't like that when I have a one method which can take a different set of arguments (overloaded) I have to click up and down arrow, to see the parameters. Can it just show me a scroll list like AndroidStudio and Eclipse? And is there a way when autocomplete some method to put automatically the braces  and semicolon- "();"? I am really new to VisualStudio and I don't know can I modified it in this way or I should have to use to it. I just don't find anything about this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to have a look at ReSharper plugin for VS. It is a complete package for enhancing Productivity, but it is not a free plugin. It also have some features you mentioned. also you can check this videos:
[Resharper features video list](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQ176FUIyIUa7pt4QLvXsspND1q-S_Zrx)

Here is the website:
[Resharper website](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)